# ASP.NET MVC Redirect To Action does not render final View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, routes

I'm trying this code:-

If no query string supplied to the Index Method then render a Branch Locator View. When a Branch Id is selected in that View, post back to a Redirect To Route Result OR Action Result method and then redirect back to Index with a query string of the selected Branch Id.

I can run through the code successfully without and then with the query string.
I even run through the Index View and can see the Model working however, the Index View does not render, the Branch Selector View remains. Network developer tools shows the correct URL with query string correctly in place when doing the Redirect.

(NOTE: Both methods are on the same controller).

If I add the same query string directly in the Browser address bar it works fine!

I have this code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var querystringbranchId = Request.QueryString["branchId"];

   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(querystringId))
   {
       ....do stuff like build a model using the branchId...

       return View(Model);
   }

   return View("BranchSelector")
}

[HttpPost]
public RedirectToRouteResult BranchDetails(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    var querystringBranchId = formCollection["BranchList"];
    var branchId = int.Parse(querystringBranchId);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { branchId });
}
```

Comment: Can you share your index view code ??

Comment: The index code just parses the Querystring to an INT to then use a service that returns a model. Thanks!

Comment: AlwaysLearning: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP please retag your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using strongly typed model on the post, and specifying the param as an actual param - Using View models is going to be much better for you.

I have tested the below - It seemed to work as expected for me:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int? branchId)
{
    if (branchId.HasValue)
    {
        return View(branchId);
    }

    return View("BranchSelector");
}

[HttpPost]
public RedirectToRouteResult BranchDetails(MyModel myModel)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { myModel.BranchId });
}

public class MyModel
{
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
}
```

**The View:**

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("BranchDetails", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.TextBox("BranchId","123")
        <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@MichaelLake Thanks to your post I found the problem. I tried your code and sure enough it works as expected. I didn't mention I was using a Kendo Combobox control (!) loaded with the branches. I didn't mention that as the actual data I needed was available in the post method so, thought the issue was with the Controller methods. I had the Kendo control name as BranchList, I changed it to BranchId and it now works with the original code as expected! The Kendo name becomes the element Id and has to match to work.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This will work for you. Cheers :D

return RedirectToAction("Index", "ControllerName", new { branchId = branchId});

Comment: Tried this initially, not required if variable name is same as querystring, thanks!